# Test project Qt project file (.pro)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, project, googletest

In one VS2010 solution, i have two projects. I have one project with source code. I created a second project folder for tests. In this second folder, there is the source code for the related tests using GTest framework.

- What is best practice: set up both project in the same .pro file, or write two separate .pro files ?
- How to have one .pro file 'call' the other ?
- How to write the .pro file(s) so as to create two distinct project in VS2010 ?

The Qt project file i am referring to is this one: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question but probably the only valid solution, if you are interested in a common ground between VS and QtCreator/qmake, is `cmake` and a cmake based building .

Comment: I would like to launch a sln that contains both projects. projects have been built with a .bat calling a .pro. could you elaborate into an answer regarding cmake?

Comment: Have you seen SUBDIRS?

Comment: Could you propose an example .pro using it ?